# Cloud agent has stopped working

Tags: gallery, cloud

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 and it worked just fine until today. The message Cloud agent has stopped working started appearing and it stops my Gallery from working. Is there a way of fixing it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should accept the answer that worked for you by ticking the green mark below the answer, to indicate that this solution worked for you

Answer (score 1):

If you have too much memory used up in your gallery delete photos. If that doesn't work what fixed it for me was logging out of drop box on my phone then logging back in. Good luck!
(I also have note 3)

Answer (score 1):

I came across an answer at another forum and it worked for me. Sigh out of Dropbox and then sign in again.

I hope it works for you all ;)